# .NET Regex for boolean logic operators

Tags: .net, regex

I have the following .NET regex:

```
(?<!["".])+?\b(AND|OR)\b\)?\s?(?=\1+|\1?$)\1?(?![.""])
```

It works great at finding words AND or OR that are NOT in between two words so that I can escape them. However I am struggling to get the regex to exclude matches where the operators are enclosed within quotes.

So for example the following should not match although normally they would if they weren't in quotes.

```
"MARS AND VENUS AND" - would match on the last AND

"MARS AND AND AND AND AND OR"-  would match on all AND words and OR
```

Comment: There are no really good ways to do that. The only thing you can do is to match content between quotes and content that is not AND OR NOT in a capture group (useful for a replacement) and then AND OR NOT. This is the only way I know in .net to avoid something. Other ways using lookbehinds are only a waste of time and are false. You can also use a split approach (splitting on content between quotes), and then check each part for AND OR NOT.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you so much finally someone has brought me back from insanity, I have spent over three days trying to figure it out no wonder I felt so deflated! Thanks for the advice. I am surprised I thought regular expressions could handle things like that.

Comment: I send you my opinion about your particular case. Since you are beginner, take care to test carefully any solutions people suggests you (try the worst edge cases), and take the time to well understand them.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thank you for all your advice. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since it looks like you know regex a little, I'm just going to post the
regex without the implementation.

You'll need the delegate replacement which is basically Dot-Net's callback.
Inside there you can decide what to replace.

Since things can be hidden in quotes, the general solution has *always* been
to match what you don't want (quoted strings, in this case),
to move the current string position beyond that point to get at what you  really want.

On the delegate callback, just replace the quoted group with itself,
otherwise, replace what you really want with something you'd like to change
on it.

Basically,

*if group 1 matched,

 return group 1

else

 return group 2 + modified group 3*

I don't know what you're trying to match actually, just guessing.
Change the whitespace boundary's back to word boundary's if you need to.
Change it to suite your needs.

`@"(""[^""]*"")|(^\s*)?(?<!\S)(AND|OR)(?!\S)\s*(?(2)|(?=(?:AND|OR)(?!\S)|$))"`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
    ( " [^"]* " )                 # (1), Match quoted terms

 |                              # OR

    ( ^ \s* )?                    # (2), BOS, used in conditional
    (?<! \S )                     # Whitespace boundary behind
    ( AND | OR )                  # (3), 'and/or'
    (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary ahead
    \s*    

    (?(2)                         # Was 'and/or' at the BOS ?
                                       # Yes, then take it
      |                              # or,
                                       # No, must be 'and/or' past it or EOS
         (?=
              (?: AND | OR )                # 'and/or'
              (?! \S )                      # Whitespace boundary ahead
           |                              # or,
              $                             # EOS
         )
    )
```